# Building Binary Tree from Pre and In order

Tags: c, binary-tree, traversal

I'm trying to build a binary tree from In-order and Pre-order.
Each node holds an integer value for data.
I ran into a problem when having these arrays:

> Pre-order: 3,9,2,6,1,1,1,4
>   In-Order: 2,9,3,1,1,1,6,4

This is the original tree from which the traversals were extracted from:

```
    3
   / \
  9   6
 /   / \
2   1   4
   / \
  1   1
```

The problem is that the function I wrote can't distinguish the consecutive equal numbers.

This is the function in C:

```
TREE createTreeFromPreAndIn(int pre[], int in[], int n){
    TREE res;
    res.root = createTreeFromPreAndInHelper(pre, in, n);
    return res;
}

TNODE* createTreeFromPreAndInHelper(int pre[], int in[], int n){
    int index;
    TNODE* rootL, *rootR, *root;

    if (n == 0)
        return NULL;
    else {
        index = findIndex(in, n, pre[0]); //returns the index of the first appearance of pre[0] in 'in'
        rootL = createTreeFromPreAndInHelper(pre+1, in, index);
        rootR = createTreeFromPreAndInHelper(pre+1+index, in+index+1, n-index-1);
        root = createNewTreeNode(pre[0], rootL, rootR);
        return root;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you have duplicates, the tree structure might be ambiguous.  Are you just looking for one solution?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for a specific solution. Is there a way to build a specific tree from pre and in orders when there are duplicates?

Comment: {In,Pre}Order are ways to traverse binary tree, after it's being built. How do you know that the sequence you've are in or pre ordered?

Comment: I extracted them from a tree I already had (I wanted to post an image of the tree but I don't have enough reputation points). In my example the "1,1,1" is actually a sub tree with 1 as a root and left and right children, both 1.

Comment: Can you be more specific about why you mean by "specific tree"?  Are you saying that you know something about the structure of the tree already, or do you mean that out of all the possible trees, you are looking for one that best matches some criteria, such as having the minimum depth?

Comment: I added a an illustration of the tree from which the In-order and Pre-order traversals were extracted from. Do you understand what my problem is?

Comment: Simply build the tree from the sequence (as done typically), don't confuse yourself with {in,pre}order traversal.

Comment: So you're suggesting that if I want to get a specific tree from a given Pre-order and In-order traversals I need to add other criteria to the function?@VaughnCato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have enough requirement to identify the exact image. Your tree above can also be expressed as

```
              Fig 1                       Fig 2                      Fig 3

                3                          3                           3   
               / \                        / \                         / \
              9   6                      9   6                       9   6
             /   / \                    /   / \                     /   / \
            2   1   4                  2   1   4                   2   1   4
               / \                        /                             \
              1   1                      1                               1 
                                        /                               / 
                                       1                               1
```

All the above tree gives the same In-order and Pre-order Sets as per your initiation.

In-order= { 2,9,3,1,1,1,6,4 }

Pre-order= { 3,9,2,6,1,1,1,4}

There is an ambiguity. So you cant identify the exact tree with this information. You have to specify additional informations to work with this problem.

If you want to recreate it, you can possibly try including boundaries in the array.

**For ex:
Use -1 to specify no-child(Assuming my node values will not be -1 at any case).**

**Fig 1:**

In-order: {-1,2,-1,9,-1,3,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,6,-1,4,-1}

Pre-order: {3,9,2,-1,-1,-1,6,1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,4,-1,-1}

**Fig 2:**

In-order: {-1,2,-1,9,-1,3,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,6,-1,4,-1}

Pre-order: {3,9,2,-1,-1,-1,6,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,4,-1,-1}

Obviously Pre-order will change and it can help you to avoid ambiguity and recreate the required structure.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Using only traversals, is there a way to determine how a tree would look like? If I give a the depth of the tree, I would still have two options for this specific tree if the tree is of depth 4 (the bottom "1,1" could be on the left or right).

Comment: Even if you specify the depth of the tree, you will encounter ambiguity with the second and the third figure above. I have depicted only 3 structures above and some more structures exists and you will face ambiguity with it. @DavidTzoor

Comment: Why your input array has only the node values. Why cant you store the boundaries in it in order to recreate the exact structure. Without specifying the boundary, you will always end up with ambiguity. @DavidTzoor

Comment: That is the way they taught us in class, but when I tried the above example I encountered the ambiguity. What do you mean by boundary? How should the 'fixed' array look like?

Comment: @DavidTzoor check the edit. It will explain you about the boundary. Its just a quick solution that flashes in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

The ambiguity arises from the fact that the leaf nodes are not fully defined.  Define a placeholder (0 or -1) for nodes not to be built, and USE parens to show the list's structure.

Pre-order: 3(9(2)(0))(6 (1(1)(1)) (4)) with parens and a placeholder zero without the parens the same sequence of numbers could be "parenthesized" as 3(9(2)(0))(6(1)(1(1)(4))).

The duplicate numbers have nothing to do with the ambiguity.  A number does not define its place in the structure.  Rather, the fact that this is a pre-order binary tree where each node (i.e. parent) has, by definition left and right children, but each child can be a parent with two children!  Thus the list of elements has to "fill-out" the tree down to its leafs.